# How do I set up index.html as top level page for my Github Pages page?

Tags: github, github-pages

I created a plain static website and deployed it on `username.github.io` However, whenever I try to access the website, I have to use the direct path to my HTML index.html file to see the site.

Is it possible to set username.github.io to display the index file? Go directly to `username.github.io` vs `username.github.io/index`?

thanks in advance

Comment: No it does not work.

Comment: Instead of simply saying "it doesn't work", please provide a [mcve] and a link to an example repo.

Comment: So, I got it to work, thank you for looking into helping. I think there was a clash between my DNS provider. I have resolved it since by fixing the DNS configurations.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new repo, name it `<username>.github.io`.
2. Add an `index.html` file.

Documentation available [here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user-and-organization-pages-sites).

Answer (score -1):

The [official documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/#add-content-and-push) is quite clear

```
cd username.github.io
echo "My Page" > index.html
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin master
```

Note that since [Dec. 2016](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3), a `README` would be enough if you do't have an `index.html` file.

Comment: Well, it quite clearly does not work in my scenario.

Comment: I followed the documentation.

Comment: @a_g what is your repository?